# Run command after one process (by pid) complete

Tags: windows, linux

I need to check if a process complete or not by shell script (linux and windows). What I know is the process ID. Once the process complete, the shell will call other commands. Could someone tell me how to write the shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux you can use ps -p $PID to check the process, so you could write a while loop that checks e.g. `ps -p $PID | wc -l` (this counts the lines, if the process is finished the output will result in less lines). you could break the while loop under this condition and then all the other code would be executed. I cannot write a snippet, because I do not have an access to a shell at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong ... I think you are trying to check whether the process has completed or not. If yes, you can do so like

Linux:

```
ps -ef|grep pid|grep -v grep
```

Windows:

```
tasklist /FI PID eq "PID Value"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It really help. I will try them first.

Answer (score 0):

In  case you need to use  it in  Java or  some  other  languages  you can  use  one of following  command  strings.

Windows:

```
cmd /c tasklist /FI "PID eq  pidStr"
```

Linux:

```
ps -p  pidStr
```

Windows Example:

```
C:\Windows\System32>cmd /c tasklist /FI "PID eq 5565"
INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.

C:\Windows\System32>cmd /c tasklist /FI "PID eq 11144"

Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
bash.exe                     11144 Console                    1      4,808 K
```